# Transaction Check Error:

Tags: cassandra, yum, datastax, rhel

I am trying to install cassandra on rhel through yum installation. but i am getting size is not sufficient error.

```
Total size: 538 M
Installed size: 638 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  installing package dse-libmahout-4.7.3-1.noarch needs 52MB on the / filesystem
  installing package dse-libcassandra-4.7.3-1.noarch needs 100MB on the / filesystem
  installing package dse-libhadoop-native-4.7.3-1.x86_64 needs 101MB on the / filesystem
  installing package datastax-agent-5.2.0-1.noarch needs 127MB on the / filesystem
  installing package dse-libpig-4.7.3-1.noarch needs 144MB on the / filesystem
  installing package dse-demos-4.7.3-1.noarch needs 231MB on the / filesystem
  installing package dse-libhadoop-4.7.3-1.noarch needs 254MB on the / filesystem
  installing package dse-libtomcat-4.7.3-1.noarch needs 260MB on the / filesystem
  installing package opscenter-5.2.0-1.noarch needs 384MB on the / filesystem
  installing package dse-liblog4j-4.7.3-1.noarch needs 384MB on the / filesystem
  installing package dse-libhive-4.7.3-1.noarch needs 424MB on the / filesystem
  installing package dse-libsolr-4.7.3-1.noarch needs 499MB on the / filesystem
  installing package dse-libsqoop-4.7.3-1.noarch needs 502MB on the / filesystem

Error Summary
-------------
Disk Requirements:
  At least 502MB more space needed on the / filesystem.

#df -h
-4.7.3]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_VolGroup00-lv_root
                      4.4G  4.0G  186M  96% /
tmpfs                  16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1            477M   85M  368M  19% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_VolGroup00-lv_home
                      430M  2.4M  405M   1% /home
/dev/xvdb1            197G   60M  187G   1% /data
/dev/xvdc1             99G   60M   94G   1% /local/apps
[root@ip-10-162-2-98 dse-4.7.3]#
[root@ip-10-162-2-98 dse-4.7.3]#
```

and i find the system space as above. I am not sure of which space is used for installation. so can you help me in fixing this problem. It would be really great help if you can suggest me soemthing as I have no knowedge on these issues. sorry for few basic questions. I am still learning.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Error summary says "At least 502MB more space needed on the / filesystem". From your `df` output it can be observed that only 186M disk space is available for `/` filesystem which is not enough.

First option to solve issue is to install package on `/data` or `/local/apps` (since these partitions are large enough). Use `rpm` option `--prefix` to install package in different directory (if package is relocatable)

Example: Command to install package in /home/newroot directory

`rpm --prefix=/home/newroot/ <package_name>.rpm`

Other option is to resize volume vg_VolGroup00-lv_root if possible.

Comment: Hi Pardeshi, thank you very much for your time.. I am trying to install using the below command:

    sudo yum install dse-full

i have datastax.repo file configured. I am not sure on how i need to use the above rpm command to change dir installation. could you kindly tell on how i can apply that? Many thanks again

Comment: Please use yum install  <package name>  --installroot=<newroot> (let <newroot> directory on your /data or /local/apps since it has enough space)

Comment: thanks for your help pardesh. i tried above command but its not working.